# NHibernate Query Generator with Fluent mappings

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-criteria

I was trying to find a good way to build dynamic queries with NHibernate and that lead me to NHibernate Query Generator which I like but we currently use Fluent NHibernate mappings and I wasn't sure if there was a way to use NHibernate Query Generator with Fluent NHibernate mappings. Any one have experience with this or know a better way to accomplish dynamic queries?

Answer (score 0):

First, NHibernate already has ways to build dynamic queries (**Criteria** / **QueryOver** are specially useful for this). I googled "NHibernate Query Generator" and found a project that was abandoned more than 4 years ago.

Second, the method you use to create your mappings has nothing to do with the query APIs.